# Executing a string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a requirement where I have some conditions saved in DB. I am able to bring those conditions via my PHP code, But I am not able to execute them. I have shown one example below.

```
<? 

$z = ">100";//I get this value from the DB
$x = 80; // This value also comes from DB

if(exec("&1 &2",$x,$z))
  echo "Yes";
else
  echo "No";
?>
```

Also tried This

```
<? 

$z = ">100";
$x = 80;
if(eval("$x $z"))
  echo "Yes";
else
  echo "No";
?>
```

Comment: [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec) is meant for shell commands. [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) runs dynamic code.

Comment: Not to be a troll, but remember, "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question."  -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Comment: What happens when you try the second block of code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#114731

Comment: I get this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in E:\wamp\www\test\test.php(3) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: if only  your requirements meet, I suggest to straight away use separator between operator and number, then explode it !

Comment: Am not getting you. Can you plz write the code for exploding?

Comment: @KarthikRajagopalan " eval only accepts statements, not expressions ", check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be, ( `eval` only accepts statements, not expressions)

```
$z = ">100";//I get this value from the DB
$x = 80; // This value also comes from DB


if(eval("return {$x} {$z};"))
  echo "Yes";
else
  echo "No";
?>
```